How do I get these variables into my powershell script from pipeline in in jenkins
I have the following pipeline script to get the current git tag that my multibranch pipeline has just checked out along with the current workspace. echo "TAG: ${TAG}" and echo "Workspace Path: ${workspacePath}" show me the correct git tag and path but I cannot get it into my powershell script.
pipeline {
agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        // We perform a git command onto the latest repo just checked out
                        def cmd = new StringBuilder()
                        cmd.append("git describe --tags")
                        
                        // We format the return of the command into the tag itself
                        def TAG = bat(
                            returnStdout: true,
                            script: "${cmd.toString()}"
                        )
                        echo "TAG: ${TAG}"

                        // Print the current workspace path
                        def workspacePath = pwd()
                        echo "Workspace Path: ${workspacePath}"

                        withEnv(["RELEASE_TAG_NAME=$TAG", "WORKSPACE_PATH=$workspacePath"]){
                        powershell'''
                        & "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\controlled_build_script.ps1" 
                        -RELEASE_TAG_NAME ${env:RELEASE_TAG_NAME} 
                        -WORKSPACE_PATH ${env:WORKSPACE_PATH} 
                        '''
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


How do you know the values are not passed to the script? Are you printing them? What do you see?

Sorry for not making that clear, in my powershell script I have a check for the input variables to see if they are empty or null and this error gets triggered making me believe that it is not passed into the script.

I see multiple overcomplications in your script, and they seem to hide the simple reason behind your issue.
You have two options:

use Groovy syntax and Groovy string interpolation to construct your command. You seemed to try this but you have to use a dot instead of a colon: ${env.RELEASE_TAG_NAME} - because you're accessing the env Groovy variable set by Jenkins. Note that this requires usage of double quotes (") instead of ('), and is strongly discouraged when working with secrets;
use the shell string interpolation - that means you have to use the shell-native way of variable substitution. I don't remember PowerShell syntax but I assume it would be either something like %%RELEASE_TAG_NAME%% or accessing env without the curly braces like $env:RELEASE_TAG_NAME.

Now, to the other issues I see:

you don't need to use a StringBuilder()
and there's no need to use a separate variable if you don't do anything else with that script. Note that Jenkins processes the Groovy code on the controller, so the less Groovy code you have, the better. So, the following is more than enough:
def TAG = bat(
  returnStdout: true,
  script: 'git describe --tags'
)

Moreover, depending on you pipeline type, this might also be available as an existing environment variable;
echo "TAG: ${TAG}" will clutter the log output and print itself first. Instead, if you're within a script block, you can use println;
also, you can use the label parameter of the bat step instead of the comment in the code;
depending on the pipeline context, def workspacePath = pwd() could be either redundant or incorrect as the workspace path (which is available through the WORKSPACE environment variable set by Jenkins itself) not necessary the current directory (that might change if you use, say, a dir step):
...
steps {
  script {
    println env.WORKSPACE // smth like 'D:\Jenkins\workspaces\job1-branch1'
    println pwd // same as above
    dir('mydirectory') {
      println env.WORKSPACE // still 'D:\Jenkins\workspaces\job1-branch1'
      println pwd // 'D:\Jenkins\workspaces\job1-branch1\mydirectory'
    }
  }
}


most likely, you can replace withEnv with a more convenient environment block to simplify your scripts and reduce the number of variables;
I might be wrong as I don't usually work with Windows and PowerShell but in multiline strings you most likely have to escape the line endings with a backslash;
if you have control over the script you're running, it makes sense to make it actually read the environment variables instead of duplicating them as parameters.

To sum up, I think your pipeline could look like this:
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      environment {
        RELEASE_TAG_NAME = bat
          script: 'git describe --tags',
          returnStdout: true,
          label 'Detecting the release tag'
      }
      steps {
        script {
          println "Workspace: $env.WORKSPACE"
          powershell '''
            & "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\controlled_build_script.ps1" \
              -RELEASE_TAG_NAME $env:RELEASE_TAG_NAME \
              -WORKSPACE_PATH $env:WORKSPACE
          '''
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


Curly brackets around powershell variables are perfectly fine. Unnecessary in this case, but still fine.

echo "TAG: ${TAG}" will duplicate the output in the logs - this is wrong. In Jenkins DSL println is a synonym of echo in most cases. The only exception is src of a shared library, where println prints to the controller log instead of the workflow log.

And passing parameters explicitly is always preferred to using global state, like env. The OP is doing the right thing.


will duplicate the output in the logs - this is wrong - I might have phrased this incorrectly. What I mean is that the log would contain cluttering records like echo/echo STRING_TO_OUTPUT, and only after that it would contain the desired output. Regarding "always preferred" - no it's not, it depends on the case. In this one, at least one of the variables is already available globally, and the whole attempt to pass it explicitly basically caused the subject issue.



contain cluttering records - echo, print, and println work exactly the same in steps and in script` blocks. At least in declarative pipeline.


Same in scripted pipeline.

It looks like you are trying to use multiline powershell call, but don't use the grave accent (backtick). See line continuation documentation. So it should be
powershell '''
    & "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\controlled_build_script.ps1" `
        -RELEASE_TAG_NAME ${env:RELEASE_TAG_NAME} `
        -WORKSPACE_PATH ${env:WORKSPACE_PATH} 
'''


I managed to do what I intended by using a jenkins File to call a job which calls a script, this way I can decouple the jenkins file with what I want it to do so that it does not have to change.
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            script {
                println "WORKSPACE: $env.WORKSPACE"
                println "RELEASE_TAG_NAME: $env.TAG_NAME"
                println "BRANCH_NAME: $env.BRANCH_NAME"

                build job: 'tag_builder', 
                parameters: [
                    string(name: 'RELEASE_TAG', value: "$env.TAG_NAME"),
                    string(name: 'WORKSPACE_PATH', value: "$env.WORKSPACE"),
                    string(name: 'NAME_BRANCH', value: "$env.BRANCH_NAME")
                ]
                
            }
        }
    }
}

Which then gives the parameters to a powershell script using the powershell plugin which is not available from the Groovy side of jenkins
